# code that works in VB but not in C# using ftd2xx.dll

Tags: c#, vb.net

ok  have this in VB:

```
  Public Function xcCommGetDevicesList() As List(Of String)
    '********************************************************'
    '** Load USB Devices to the Combo Box
    '** Gets a list of all available MXDPP's connected on the computer and 
    '** populate them in a list of strings which is returned
    '********************************************************'

    Dim vDeviceList As New List(Of String)  'Stores list of devices found
    Dim vDeviceCount As Integer             'Stores the number of devices attached
    Dim vDevice As String                   'Stores the name of the device  
    Dim vIndex As Integer                   'Index of device request

    Try
        'Request the number of FTDI devices attached to computer
        vFT_Status = FT_GetNumberOfDevices(vDeviceCount, vbNullChar, cFT_LIST_NUMBER_ONLY)

        'Check if the return value was OK
        If vFT_Status = cFT_OK Then

            'Loop through each device attached and add to cmbDevices if it is an MXDPP
            For vIndex = 0 To vDeviceCount - 1

                'Allocate space in the string variable (It doesn't work if you don't do this)
                vDevice = Space(64)

                'Request the description of the device at the specified vIndex
                vFT_Status = FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX Or cFT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION)

                'Check if the return value was OK
                If vFT_Status = cFT_OK Then

                    'Remove null character from description
                    vDevice = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(vDevice, InStr(1, vDevice, vbNullChar) - 1)

                    'Determine if device is and MXDPP-50 add it to cmbDevices if it is
                    If vDevice.Contains("MXDPP-50") Then

                        'Allocate space in the string variable (It doesn't work if you don't do this)
                        vDevice = Space(16)

                        'Request the name of the device at the specified vIndex
                        vFT_Status = FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX Or cFT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER)

                        'Check if the return value was OK
                        If vFT_Status = cFT_OK Then
                            'Remove null character and save name to Device array 
                            vDeviceList.Add(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(vDevice, InStr(1, vDevice, vbNullChar) - 1))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


    'Return vDeviceList to calling function
    Return vDeviceList
End Function
```

and this in C#

```
    public static List<string> DPP_GetDeviceList()
    {
        //********************************************************'
        //** Get Device List
        //** Gets a list of all available MXDPP's connected on the computer and
        //** populate them in a list of strings which is returned
        //********************************************************'

        List<string> vDeviceList = new List<string>(); //Stores list of devices found
        int vDeviceCount = default(int); //Stores the number of devices attached
        string vDevice = default(string); //Stores the name of the device
        int vIndex = default(int); //Index of device request

        try
        {
            //Request the number of FTDI devices attached to computer
            vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetNumberOfDevices(ref vDeviceCount, Constants.vbNullChar, cFT_LIST_NUMBER_ONLY));

            //Check if the return value was OK
            if (vFT_Status == cFT_OK)
            {

                //Loop through each device attached and add to List if it is an MXDPP
                for (vIndex = 0; vIndex <= vDeviceCount - 1; vIndex++)
                {

                    //Allocate space in the string variable (It doesn't work if you don't do this)
                    vDevice = Strings.Space(64);

                    //Request the description of the device at the specified vIndex
                    //vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX | cFT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION));
                    vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX | cFT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER));

                    //Check if the return value was OK
                    if (vFT_Status == cFT_OK)
                    {

                        //Remove null character from description
                        vDevice = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(vDevice, vDevice.IndexOf(Constants.vbNullChar) + 0);

                        //Determine if device is and MXDPP-50 add it to list if it is
                        if (vDevice.Contains("MXDPP-50"))
                        {

                            //Allocate space in the string variable (It doesn't work if you don't do this)
                            vDevice = Strings.Space(16);

                            //Request the name of the device at the specified vIndex
                            vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX | cFT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER));

                            //Check if the return value was OK
                            if (vFT_Status == cFT_OK)
                            {
                                //Remove null character and save name to Device array
                                vDeviceList.Add(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(vDevice, vDevice.IndexOf(Constants.vbNullChar) + 0));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Err)
        {
            //Handle Errors Here
        }

        //Return vDeviceList to calling function
        return vDeviceList;
    }
```

now after this this line :

```
 vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX | cFT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER));
```

in C# VDevice is blank

but in VB

```
 vFT_Status = FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX Or cFT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER)
```

it have the right information in VDevice

now both classes uses 
ftd2xx.dll

D2XX drivers allow direct access to the USB device through a DLL.  Application software can access the USB device through a series of DLL function calls.  The functions available are listed in the  D2XX Programmer's Guide document which is available from the Documents section of this site.

Programming examples using the D2XX drivers and DLL can be found in the Projects section of this site.

C#

```
[DllImport("FTD2XX.DLL",EntryPoint="FT_ListDevices", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern int FT_GetNumberOfDevices(ref int lngNumberOfDevices, string pvArg2, int lngFlags);
    [DllImport("FTD2XX.DLL",EntryPoint="FT_ListDevices", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern int FT_GetDeviceString(int lngDeviceIndex, string lpszDeviceString, int lngFlags);
    [DllImport("FTD2XX.DLL", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
```

VB

```
 Private Declare Function FT_GetNumberOfDevices Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" Alias "FT_ListDevices" (ByRef lngNumberOfDevices As Integer, ByVal pvArg2 As String, ByVal lngFlags As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function FT_GetDeviceString Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" Alias "FT_ListDevices" (ByVal lngDeviceIndex As Integer, ByVal lpszDeviceString As String, ByVal lngFlags As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function FT_GetDeviceInfo Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal lngHandle As Integer, ByRef lngFT_Type As Integer, ByRef lngID As Integer, ByVal pucSerialNumber As String, ByVal pucDescription As String, ByRef pvDummy As Byte) As Integer
```

UPDATE:

```
    public static List<string> DPP_GetDeviceList()
    {
        //********************************************************'
        //** Get Device List
        //** Gets a list of all available MXDPP's connected on the computer and
        //** populate them in a list of strings which is returned
        //********************************************************'

        List<string> vDeviceList = new List<string>(); //Stores list of devices found
        int vDeviceCount = default(int); //Stores the number of devices attached
        StringBuilder vDevice = default(StringBuilder); //Stores the name of the device
        int vIndex = default(int); //Index of device request

        try
        {
            //Request the number of FTDI devices attached to computer
            vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetNumberOfDevices(ref vDeviceCount, Constants.vbNullChar, cFT_LIST_NUMBER_ONLY));

            //Check if the return value was OK
            if (vFT_Status == cFT_OK)
            {

                //Loop through each device attached and add to List if it is an MXDPP
                for (vIndex = 0; vIndex <= vDeviceCount - 1; vIndex++)
                {

                    //Allocate space in the string variable (It doesn't work if you don't do this)
                    //vDevice = StringBuilder

                    //Request the description of the device at the specified vIndex
                    //vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX | cFT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION));
                    vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX | cFT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER));

                    //Check if the return value was OK
                    if (vFT_Status == cFT_OK)
                    {

                        //Remove null character from description
                        //vDevice = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(vDevice, vDevice.IndexOf(Constants.vbNullChar) + 0);

                        //Determine if device is and MXDPP-50 add it to list if it is
                    //  if (vDevice.Contains("MXDPP-50"))
                        {

                            //Allocate space in the string variable (It doesn't work if you don't do this)
                        //  vDevice = Strings.Space(16);

                            //Request the name of the device at the specified vIndex
                            vFT_Status = System.Convert.ToInt32(FT_GetDeviceString(vIndex, vDevice, cFT_LIST_BY_INDEX | cFT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER));

                            //Check if the return value was OK
                            if (vFT_Status == cFT_OK)
                            {
                                //Remove null character and save name to Device array
                                //vDeviceList.Add(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(vDevice, vDevice.IndexOf(Constants.vbNullChar) + 0));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Err)
        {
            //Handle Errors Here
        }

        //Return vDeviceList to calling function
        return vDeviceList;
    }
```

Also,

```
//********************************************************'

    [DllImport("FTD2XX.DLL",EntryPoint="FT_ListDevices", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern int FT_GetNumberOfDevices(ref int lngNumberOfDevices, string pvArg2, int lngFlags);
    [DllImport("FTD2XX.DLL",EntryPoint="FT_ListDevices", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
    //private static extern int FT_GetDeviceString(int lngDeviceIndex, string lpszDeviceString, int lngFlags);
    private static extern int FT_GetDeviceString(int lngDeviceIndex, StringBuilder lpszDeviceString, int lngFlags);
    [DllImport("FTD2XX.DLL", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
```

but again,
that did not work... Vdevice was still blank...

Comment: try with `private static extern int FT_GetDeviceString(int lngDeviceIndex, StringBuilder lpszDeviceString, int lngFlags);`. Ensure the StringBuilder you pass to the function is nitialized with 64 chars size (also with this you can remove the Spaces call).

Comment: The declaration is wrong.  System.String is an immutable type so must not be modified by the native code.  The damage done to the GC heap is unpredictable.  This must be a StringBuilder.  It must be initialized with sufficient Capacity to receive the string.

Comment: Hans, so what should I change ?

Comment: Gusman, that did not work

Comment: Update the code to see what you have changed, also, did it throw any exception or something?

Comment: there is no error , vDevice is just blank . again in the VB it is not blank

Comment: Gusman I made the changes you said, but it did not work. So I put the code back the way it was.

Comment: He's asking you to update your post with the code you are now using.

Comment: so I added the line he has  private static extern int FT_GetDeviceString(int lngDeviceIndex, StringBuilder lpszDeviceString, int lngFlags); but it did the same thing. so I put the code back to the way it was.

Comment: Ugh.  Use the edit link under your post to update your question.  Include the code showing us how you used it.

Comment: also with the StringBuilder, I had to change other things too but I could not use vDevice = Strings.Space(64);

Comment: ok I updated it, but again it did not work

Comment: This isn't going anywhere.  Use the managed wrapper library provided by FTDI: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp.htm

Comment: I tried that ... most of their example projects do not work and the one that did work, I could not get to work on with my code...

Comment: can anyone else help ?

Comment: Try `StringBuilder vDevice = new StringBuilder(64);`

Comment: ok I did but is just has 64 0s or '/0's in it

Comment: really do not see how this work in the VB code but not the C#

Comment: can anyone help ?